# Linux make file

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to have php write a file using ssh2 connection.

I'm trying to write a file that contains this:

```
generator-settings=
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false
allow-flight=false
announce-player-achievements=true
server-port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=false
spawn-animals=true
snooper-enabled=true
hardcore=false
online-mode=true
resource-pack=
pvp=true
difficulty=1
enable-command-block=false
player-idle-timeout=0
gamemode=0
max-players=40
spawn-monsters=true
view-distance=5
generate-structures=true
spawn-protection=16
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

I'm trying to use this `echo -n '.$serverp.' > server.properties`

$serverp is getting from a data base that large chunk of text.

If anyone could help thanks :)

Comment: You're not telling us about your error

Comment: gives me no error, dose not make file.

Comment: are you using `echo -n` as in the shell command not as in `echo` the php command? you need to use `exec` or `shell_exec` to run shell commands from php

Comment: I'm doing this with ssh2_exec because I need the file written on a different server not the web server.

Comment: so you must be following the manual here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php right? you need to post your code that makes the connection to the remote shall and executes the script

Comment: //not going to give you connect info ;)
$serverp = $mc['server.properties'];
$makefile = ssh2_exec($sshconn, 'echo -n '.$serverp.' > file');

yes the connection works fine I tested it by making a dir on the server.